# Function in onclick method not working - JAVASCRIPT NOT JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

I have a form which the submit button wont execute the function being called onclick.

```
<form method="get" name="myform" onsubmit="return Validate()" style="margin: 100px">
  <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="Authorise" onclick="Clear_Message(Authorise_Message)"/>
    Yes
  <input type="radio" id="No" name="Authorise" onclick="Clear_Message(Authorise_Message)" />
    No
  <div class="Output" id="Authorise_Message"> </div>
  <input type="submit" id="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" onclick="Validator()"/>
</form>
```

The Validator code:

```
function Validator()
{
    //display an error message if radio button groups have no value, if it does have a value then clear the error message
    Title_Radio();
    Gender_Radio();
    Partnership_Radio();
    Communication_Radio();
    Authorise_Radio();
    Advice_Radio();
    CC_Radio();
    Switch();

    alert("This function was called");
}
```

The radio methods check if the radio has a value, if not then it changes the Authorise_Method div to show a message next to the radios,

But the method wont seem to execute. When i had this in an `<input type="button" onclick="Validator"/>` it seemed to work but i needed it to submit so i changed it to a submit type button...

Comment: Did you mean `onClick="return Validator();"`?

Comment: nope, the onclick function being called is purely for display the errors only, but will that work??

Comment: Do you prevent the `submit` `get` mechanism?

Comment: what does that mean? im a beginner at HTML

Comment: Your click function is getting triggered but since it also has `type="submit"` so its getting submitted also see https://output.jsbin.com/quyuke for demo. I don't think its the desired functionality. So basically you  should be validating inside submit function, not `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign id to the form and then run your code at the `submit` event before the form being submitted, and prevent the form submission if the validation failed.

So the html should be:

```
<form id="theForm" method="get" name="myform" style="margin: 100px">
    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="Authorise" onclick="Clear_Message('Authorise_Message')"/> Yes
    <input type="radio" id="No" name="Authorise" onclick="Clear_Message('Authorise_Message')" /> No
    <div class="Output" id="Authorise_Message"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

And you should add the following code to your JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        Validator();
        //if the validation fails, prevent the form submission by calling the following function:
        //event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```